# Technical details on where GKE persistent volumes

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

can anyone provide technical details on where GKE persistent volumes are actually stored and what happens in case a node goes down on Google Kubernetes Engine?

Google provides documentation on the use but not on annotations, I need to know whether for any reason the PV might be stored on the node hosting the pod itself

Answer (score 3):

When the node goes down or is deleted, the GKE persistent volume will be deleted as well. This is because the default storageclass in GKE is set to  `ReclaimPolicy: Delete`

You can run the command `kubectl get sc` to check the storageclasses and
describe the storageclass by running the command `kubectl describe sc standard-rwo`

Read this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes) for more information about Persistent volumes and dynamic provisioning.

If you want to retain your Persistent volumes when the node goes down or is deleted. You can create your storageclass and set `ReclaimPolicy: Retain`, see example below:

**StorageClass**

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: mystorageclass
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  fstype: ext4
  replication-type: none
reclaimPolicy: Retain
```

Then create PVC to automatically provision your Persistent volumes and use it in your deployment. See example of PVC below:

**PersistentVolumeClaims**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mypvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
  storageClassName: mystorageclass
```